# Generate a list of keywords using Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am curious if it is possible to generate a list of keywords, a index if you will, for easy reference by doxygen ? I am not talking of list of classes etc. but specific words that are used as indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but AFAIK only with the Latex/pdf output, with the command `\addindex`

See [the manual](http://doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdaddindex).

If anybody knows a way to produce an index with the HTML, I would be very interested too.

Comment: Yes, this is also what I had figured out. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[xrefitem](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem)

With this you can create a page for each of your keywords.  One example they already make an alias for:

```
\xrefitem todo "Todo" "Todo List"
```

You can add other aliases in your Doxygen file:

```
ALIASES += "reminder=\xrefitem reminders \"Reminder\" \"Reminders\""
```

Then in the code you can do something like:

```
\reminder Add the cool feature here.
```

And you'll get a Reminder page with the list of reminders on it.